# Upgrade sites from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, upgrade

I have upgraded database from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and only 2 site collections giving below error:

> Feature upgrade action 'CustomUpgradeAction.VideoAndRichMedia' threw
>   an exception upgrading Feature 'AssetLibrary' (Id: 15/'4bcccd
>   af-46dc-a7d4-e38277ef33f4') in Site
>   'http://spserver:10000/sites/CSCAfterHoursSupport-Nightline':
>   Provisioning did not succeed ails: Failed to create the 'Style
>   Library' library. OriginalException: A list, survey, discussion board,
>   or document library with pecified title already exists in this Web
>   site.  Please choose another title.   (EventID:aj2bj)
>
> Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'AssetLibrary' (Id:
>   15/'4bcccd62-dcaf-46dc-a7d4-e38277ef33f4') in Site 'http://spserver
>   0/sites/CSCAfterHoursSupport-Nightline'. Exception: Provisioning did
>   not succeed. Details: Failed to create the 'Style Library' li .
>   OriginalException: A list, survey, discussion board, or document
>   library with the specified title already exists in this Web sit lease
>   choose another title.  (Inner Exception: A list, survey, discussion
>   board, or document library with the specified title alre xists in this
>   Web site.  Please choose another title.)  (EventID:ajy6m)
>
> Feature upgrade action 'CustomUpgradeAction.VideoAndRichMedia' threw
>   an exception upgrading Feature 'AssetLibrary' (Id: 15/'4bcccd
>   af-46dc-a7d4-e38277ef33f4') in Site
>   'http://spserver:10000/sites/RSSC': Provisioning did not succeed.
>   Details: Failed to creat  'Style Library' library. OriginalException:
>   A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the
>   specified title alread sts in this Web site.  Please choose another
>   title.     (EventID:aj2bj)
>
> Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'AssetLibrary' (Id:
>   15/'4bcccd62-dcaf-46dc-a7d4-e38277ef33f4') in Site 'http://spserver
>   0/sites/RSSC'. Exception: Provisioning did not succeed. Details:
>   Failed to create the 'Style Library' library. OriginalException: t,
>   survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title
>   already exists in this Web site.  Please choose another .  (Inner
>   Exception: A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with
>   the specified title already exists in this Web sit lease choose
>   another title.)    (EventID:ajy6m)

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved after deleting 'Style Library' from the both sites and upgrade command worked.